# Regex to parse a multiline HTML

Tags: html, regex, perl, html-parsing, multiline

am trying to parse a multi-line html file using regex.

HTML code:

```
<td>Details</td></tr>  
<tr class=d1>
<td>uss_vod_translator</td>
```

Regex Expression:

```
if ($line =~ m/Details<\/td>\s*<\/tr>\s*<tr\s*class=d1>\s*<td>(\w*)<\/td>/)
{
    print "$1";
}
```

I am using `/s*` (space) for multi-line, but it is not working. I searched about it, even used `/\?` for multi-line but that too did not work.

Can any one please suggest me how to parse a multiline HTML?

I know regex is a poor solution to parse HTML. But i have a legacy HTML code which i need to parse and have no other choice.

Comment: [Regex is a poor solution for parsing HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1583), in general.

Comment: Judging by your variable name, You only have one line, so how can match something that spans more than one line?

Comment: The best possible answer has been written some time ago by someone else: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1065241

Answer (score 12):

> Can any one please suggest me how to parse a multiline HTML?

Stop trying to use regular expressions and use a module that will parse it for you.

[HTML::TreeBuilder](https://metacpan.org/module/HTML::TreeBuilder) is a good solution.

[HTML::TreeBuilder::LibXML](https://metacpan.org/module/HTML::TreeBuilder::LibXML) gives you the same API but backed by a fast parser.

[HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath](https://metacpan.org/module/HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath) adds XPath support as well as a fast parser.

Answer (score 0):

As stated above **Never use regexes to parse HTML**.

I'm using HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath to parse HTML and this *dramatically* decrease creation time for each of my scraping/parsing programs.

Here is how you task could be implemented:

```
use Modern::Perl;
use HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath;

my $html = <<END;
<tr><td>General Info</td></tr>  
<tr class=d1>
<td>some info</td></tr>
<tr><td>Details</td></tr>  
<tr class=d1>
<td>uss_vod_translator</td></tr>
<tr><td>Another header</td></tr>  
<tr class=d1>
<td>some other info</td></tr>
END

my $tree = HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath->new_from_content($html);

my ($details) = $tree->findvalues('//tr[ td[ text() = "Details" ] ]/following-sibling::tr[1]/td[1]');
say $details;
```

Answer (score -3):

Try the below line before you match your pattern

```
 $line=~s/>(\n|\t|\s)+</></gs;
```

Then you can made the HTML string as in single line.